# How to create custom filter for active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

The default filter options for referrer and referrals shows user object references instead of their email.

I need to create custom filter for active admin based on a referrer's email and  each users referrals email.

for the first case i did

```
filter :referrer, as: :select, collection: proc {User.all.map{|u| [u.email, u.id]}}
```

This gave a drop down list for referrer filter.

But how to do the same for referrals?

every user may have more than one referrals and some may have none.

```
filter :referrals, as: :select, collection: proc {User.all.map {|u| u.referrals.map { |r| [r.email,r.id] }.map { |e,id| [e,id] }}}
```

This is what i tried and it gives out an error `undefined method`map' for nil:NilClass`

It happens for the users who doesn't have any referrals.

Any insight on how to achieve this?

Comment: how the going with the issue?

Comment: Oh, sorry i couldn't get back to this... I was doing this for a client project and after spending almost few hours to this said its not necessary... but i would like to try it out...

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know on a few days... :) Thanks for your help anyways...